# Центрирование span по вертикали поверх картинки

Tags: html, css

Добрый день! Есть такая задачка, не могу отцентрировать по вертикали блок span.

CSS

```
.example2 
    {
      display:inline-block;   
      position:relative;
      height:241px;
    }

   .example2 span {
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;   
    left:0px;
    width:460px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px; 
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    padding:10px 30px;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="slider">
 <ul>               
  <li><div class="example2"><a href=""><img src="images/01.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /><span class="s1"><span>Статья1</span></span></a></div></li>
  <li><div class="example2"><a href=""><img src="images/02.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /><span class="s1">Много текста...  Много текста... Много текста... Много текста... Много текста... Много текста...</span></a></div></li>
</ul>
```

Вот как выглядит сейчас это дело:
[image]

Что меня не устраивает, текст начинается с центра а съезжает вниз. Хотелось бы чтобы он был отцентрирован по вертикали.

Comment: Что никто не может подсказать, как реализовать центровку текста по вертикали, при этом накладывая текст на картинку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решилась следующим образом:

В css прописал такое:

```
#slider_li{margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; font: 12px Tahoma;}
#slider_li li{position: relative; width: 465px; height: 300px;}

#slider_li li a, #slider li img{position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#slider_li li a{z-index: 20;}
#slider_li li img{z-index: 10;}

#slider_li li .col{display: table-cell; position: relative; height: 300px; vertical-align: middle; z-index: 10;}
#slider_li li .col p{
    display: block; 
    padding: 15px; 
    color: #fff; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

В html написал такую структуру:

```
<div id="slider">
<ul id="slider_li">             
<li><img src="images/01.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /><span class="col"><h2>Статья1</h2></span></li>
<li><img src="images/02.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /><span class="col"><h2>Статья2</h2></span></li>
<li><img src="images/03.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /><span class="col"><h2>Статья3</h2></span></li>
<li><img src="images/04.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /><span class="col"><h2>Невероятное событие произошло сегодня утром в Москве. Новый "Тунгуский" метеорит пронесся над городом.</h2></span></li>
<li><img src="images/05.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /><span class="col"><h2>Восточная Украина. Бои под Донецком!</h2></span></li>           
</ul>
```

В итоге получилось такое:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Допустим, есть такая разметка:

```
<div class="container"><span class="centered">Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo</span></div>
```

Понадобятся такие стили:

```
/* Блок-родитель. Может быть любой ширины и высоты */
.container {
  text-align: center;
  height: 240px;  /* Для демонстрации */
  margin: 40px;   /* Для демонстрации */
}

/* Псевдоэлемент. Необходим для идеального центрирования
 * Для лучшей поддержки IE можно использовать псевдо-класс (удалить одно двоеточие) */
.container::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Так он не занимает места */
}

/* Элемент, который нужно отцентрировать. Любой ширины и высоты. */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;   /* Для демонстрации */
}

div, span {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1); /* Для демонстрации */
}
```

**[Посмотреть на результат](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/A7ESy/)**

Написано на основе замечательной статьи: **[Centering in the Unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)**

Comment: @VenZell, пример не совсем подходит. В моем случае надо текст поверх картинки накладывать, а когда я делаю по вашему примеру, блок span остается под картинкой, то есть внизу. Вот пример того что получается: http://jsfiddle.net/nR6Hm/